# Экспорт данных из PL/SQL developer

Tags: php, sql, oracle, plsql-developer

После создания и использования процедуры(IDE PL/SQL Developer) и передачи результата в PHP возникает проблема, связанная с запоминанием процедуры и не возможностью изменения её структуры.

Яркий пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выполняемый код закомментирован, **НО** он продолжает функционировать.Хотя процедура откомпилированна и сохранена.

*Вот подключение в PHP*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я плохо понял ваш вопрос, но увас оракловая процедура называется `proc2`, а в `PHP` вызывается `proc1`. Прикладывайте, пожалуйста, код текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: Вопрос заключался в том что oracle запомнил первый скомпилированный запрос.Если PL/SQL developer в test window выдаёт верный ответ, то в php приходит всё тот же как в первый запуск.

Comment: Замените скрины вашего кода на текст. Проявите уважение к тем, кто захочет повторить ваш результат.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ввод и вывод вашего кода.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась с помощью админа сервера Oracle.В связи с тем что небыли разрешены определённые права(запись/чтение/редактирование) было запрещено редактирование процедуры на самом сервере, на котором находились исходный код процедуры.Хотя редактирование в PL/SQL developer было возможно, изменение процедуры в IDE уже не учитывал сервер и использовал исходный код процедуры.